# Probability of TattsLotto, problem and answer provided, need workout

Tags: probability

**Problem Description**

In Tattslotto, a player picks a selection of $6$ numbers from the numbers $1$ to $45$. To determine the winners, $8$ numbers are chosen at random - the first $6$ are designed as the winning numbers, and the other $2$ as the supplementary numbers.
Prizes are determined as follows.

- Division 1: $6$ winning numbers
- Division 2: $5$ winning numbers and $1$ supplementary
- Division 3: $5$ winning numbers
- Division 4: $4$ winning numbers
- Division 5: $3$ winning numbers and $1$ supplementary

Find the number of combinations which satisfy each of the divisions, and hence the probabilities of winning each of the five divisions.

**Answers:**

- Division 1: $1.228 \times {10^{−7}}$
- Division 2: $1.473 \times {10^{−6}}$
- Division 3: $2.726 \times {10^{−5}}$
- Division 4: $1.365 \times {10^{−3}}$
- Division 5: $3.362 \times {10^{−3}}$

Note:
This is my daughter's homework (Year 11), I can not figure out the workout except the 1st one.

**My workout:**

- Division 1: $1 / {45 \choose 6}$
- Division 3: is NOT $1 / {45 \choose 5}$ because we chose $6$ numbers, not $5$; then I'm beginning to struggle.

Comment: Create $3$ groups - A that are $6$ winning numbers, B that are $2$ supplementary numbers and C that are $37$ ordinary numbers. Now for numerator, choose from each group the numbers as needed. For Division $3$, you choose $5$ from group A and $1$ from?... If this helps, please make an attempt. If you get stuck or want validation, pls share your working.

Comment: Also, you might consider asking your daughter help you show *some* work.  Note, the shown work belongs in the (edited) question, rather than in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The denominator will always be $\binom{45}{6} =D$

For part$2,$ it will be $\binom65\binom21 /D$

For part $3,$ it will be $\binom65\binom20\binom{37}1 /D$

You should now be  able to manage the rest