# Expected value and Lotto ball problem involving Binomial and Poisson distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, combinations, expected-value, statistical-inference

So, my question follows on from this post:
[Probability of TattsLotto, problem and answer provided, need workout](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4231696/probability-of-tattslotto-problem-and-answer-provided-need-workout)

I know how to calculate the probabilities from this post using the combination $\binom{45}{6}$ as the denominator (as per the post above)
However, I have a couple of things I would like to work out:

1. What is the probability of winnings a prize? use the fact that $\frac{P(A)}{1-P(A)}$
2. If a ticket costs $1, how many tickets should be purchased to get an expected return of 1000 dollars?

I assume the first question invokes the Law of Total probability? And then the second question uses this fact to provide an **expected value** assuming that return is calculated directly from the odds.

Finally, how would I start to analyse the following:

3. If you have bought $1000 in tickets (one dollar tickets), what is the probability of winning a prize? (Use the Poisson approximation to the binomial dist. i.e. if n is large, and p is small, then a binomial dist. (n,p) can be approximated by a Poisson dist. with mean np).

Thanks for reading.

Edit:
As pointed out, some of this doesn't make sense (That was my suspicion)
here is the problem that was taken from some university lecture notes as an un-graded 'homework' problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyXTb.jpg

Comment: "use the fact that $\frac{P(A)}{1-P(A)}$" does not state a fact

Comment: How can you work out an expected return if you do not know the size of the prizes?

Comment: I think you mean $P(\overline A)=1-P(A)$ instead of $\frac{P(A)}{1-P(A)}$,

Comment: I've gone and made an edit to show where I got this problem from.